# Find all positive integers $n$ such that $\log_2 (n)$ is a rational number.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For $\log_2(n)$ to be a rational number, I started by stating that:

$\log_2(n)=\dfrac{a}{b}$ such that $a,b \in\mathbb Z$ and $b \neq 0$

but I really don't know what step to take next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\log_2 n=\frac ab$, then 
$$2^{a/b}=n$$
or
$$2^a=n^b$$
So $n$ must be a power of two.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Raise both sides to the $2$ power, and use the fat that $$b^{\displaystyle\log_{\, b}x}=x.$$

Answer (score 0):

You are in right way. If $\log_2(n)=\dfrac{a}{b}$, then $n = 2^{\frac{a}{b}}$, then $n^b=2^a$,so $n$ must be a power of $2$.